# Function e() in javascript

Tags: javascript

Some guy showed me a piece of javascript code where there's a function called e(); that seems to be native to Javascript

This guy put a string parameter to this function like `e(dd);`, but I don't know what this function is about. I don't find any documentation about this function.

Did you guys know something about this ? Thank you, this is for my work...

Comment: If you're looking for a JavaScript function please look in google. There are tenths of websites with the list of standard JS functions.

Comment: That guy tricked you. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/dRktR/) the proof - **e is not defined**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no native function e. In the past, before using things like jQuery, I used e as an alias to document.getElementByID. This might have been common practice, but in fact e could be anything depending on the developer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function in JS. This should be some user-defined function.